# Java Broken pipe with HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, http

I'm writing a music web app, a servlet process the mp3 request, first i play mp3, playing correctly, and pause it,  then resume, i get a ClientAbortException, My container is tomcat7. I have no idea what i wrong, please give me some help. Thanks!

```
@WebServlet("/mp3")
public class Mp3Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("/Users/jiangxingshang/Documents/workspace/eclipse/MyMusic/my-music/src/main/webapp/assets/sound/1.mp3");
        try (
                SeekableByteChannel input = Files.newByteChannel(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
                WritableByteChannel output = Channels.newChannel(resp.getOutputStream())) {
            String range = req.getHeader("range");
            int pos = 0;
            if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(range)) {
                String[] tmp = StringUtils.removeStart(range, "bytes=").split("-");
                try {
                    pos = Integer.valueOf(tmp[0]);
                    input.position(pos);
                } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    pos = 0;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("start position: " + pos);
            int len = (int)Files.size(path);
            resp.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            resp.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            resp.addHeader("Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", pos, len - 1, len));
            resp.addHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=2, max=100");
            resp.addDateHeader("Last-Modified", Files.getLastModifiedTime(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toMillis());
            resp.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
            resp.setContentLength(len);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);

            while(input.read(bb) != -1) {
                bb.flip();
                output.write(bb);
                bb.clear();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Twice request header, i has remove Cookie and User-Agent header info.

First play

```
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
accept-encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
accept: */*
accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
range: bytes=0-
----------------------------------------------------------------------
start position: 0
```

When resume

```
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
accept-encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
accept: */*
accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
range: bytes=229376-
----------------------------------------------------------------------
start position: 229376
```